# Javascript: Brain.js Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, brain.js

I want create a basic AI that for each move (in input) return the best one (in output). It's just for learn and play wit Brain.js

```js
const net = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();


net.train([{
    input: [
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0
    ],
    output: [
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0
    ]
},
{
    input: [
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0
    ],
    output: [
        -1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0
    ]
},
{
    input: [
        -1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0
    ],
    output: [
        -1, 1, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0
    ]
},
{
    input: [
        -1, 1, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0
    ],
    output: [
        -1, 1, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, -1, 0
    ]
},
{
    input: [
        -1, 1, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, -1, 0
    ],
    output: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, -1, 0
    ]
},
{
    input: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, -1, 0
    ],
    output: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 0,
        -1, -1, 0
    ]
},
{
    input: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 0,
        -1, -1, 0
    ],
    output: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 0,
        -1, -1, 0
    ]
},
{
    input: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 0,
        -1, -1, 0
    ],
    output: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, -1,
        -1, -1, 0
    ]
},
{
    input: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, -1,
        -1, -1, 0
    ],
    output: [
        -1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, -1,
        -1, -1, 1
    ]
},
]);

const output = net.run([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>
```

the output is

000
010
000

Is my code right?

Comment: It's a beginning. Now, train it with lots of examples, so it can learn.

Comment: The actual code for a "perfect" tic-tac-toe is shorter and more accurate than training an AI...

Comment: @Cerbrus Yep, It's just for learn and play with Brain.js

Comment: If you happen to have a "perfect" tic tac toe player, you could also use it to generate the labeled training data for the model.

Answer (score 0):

It's a beginning. It learned that it should start at the middle if it can. Now, train it with lots of examples, so it can learn how to play in full.

Also, if you happen to have a "perfect" tic tac toe player algorithm at hand, you could use it to generate the labeled training data for the model.